# Rewrite $ \min_{q\in Q_0} \sum_{x=1}^X |m_x(q)| $ with linear objective function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have the following optimization problem
$$
\min_{q\in Q_0} \sum_{x=1}^X |m_x(q_{1})|
$$
where

- $q\equiv (q_1,q_2)$ is a vector that should satisfy a bunch of **non-linear** constraints collected in $Q_0$.
- $m_x(q_1)$ is linear in $q_1$ $\forall x=1,...,X$.

  ---

**Specifically**: some components of $q_2$ are required to be binary, other are allowed to vary in $[l_b, l_u]$; all the elements of $q_1$ are allowed to vary in $[l_b, l_u]$; apart from such support restrictions, $Q_0$ contains inequalities of the type e.g.,
$$
\overbrace{q_{1,j}}^{\in [l_b,l_u]}-\overbrace{q_{1,k}}^{\in [l_b,l_u]}\geq \overbrace{q_{2,h}}^{\text{binary}}
$$
where $q_{1,j}$ is the $j$th element of $q_1$.

In other words, what I want to highlight (sorry for the non-formal, maybe wrong terminology) is that all the inequalities in $Q_0$ would have been linear if all the elements in $q_2$ were allowed to freely vary in $[l_b, l_u]$.

---

**Question:** I have been advised that the problem above can be rewritten as having a linear objective function, because it is equivalent to
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\min_{q, \{\mu^{+}(x), \mu^{-}(x)\}_{\forall x =1,...,X}} \sum_{x=1}^X (\mu^{+}(x)+\mu^{-}(x))\\
& q\in Q_0\\
& \mu^{+}(x)\geq 0 \text{ }\forall x=1,...,X\\
& \mu^{+}(x)\geq 0\text{ }\forall x=1,...,X\\
& m_x(q)=\mu^{+}(x)-\mu^{-}(x)\text{ }\forall x=1,...,X\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Is this correct? If yes, could you skectch a proof? If not, why?

My impression is that the reformulation of the problem works when $Q_0$ contains constraints that are linear in $q$ (e.g., p.294 of Boyd and
Vandenberghe, 2004). When $Q_0$ has non-linear constraints (as in my case) I have doubts.

Comment: you are right, $Q_0$ has to be linear

Comment: Thanks. Is there any hope to get a linear objective function when $Q_0$ is non-linear? Maybe with other types of reformulations?

Comment: yes, sometimes such as when $Q_0$ is piecewise linear and convex

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks. I have added details on my problem which may allow to provide a more detailed answer. Maybe.

Comment: Binary variables will never be linear.